# IP и MAC-адрес компьютера

Tags: сеть, ip, ip-address, mac-address

Какие существуют программы для изменения IP и MAC-адреса компьютера, роутера?
Какие данные компьютера, роутера фиксируются при выходе в Интернет?
Какие данные фиксирует провайдер: программы для определения IP и MAC-адреса компьютера, роутера другого пользователя (например, узнать, с какого IP и MAC-адреса компьютера, роутера размещено объявление в Интернете)?

Comment: Какая вам нужна ОС?

Comment: @Женьок, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 2):

**В Windows 7 сменить MAC адрес:**

1. Заходите в Менеджер оборудования (Device manager).
2. Находите раскрывающийся список Сетевое оборудование (Network adapters).
3. Находите свою сетевую карту и нажимаете на нее левой кнопкой, там выбираете "Свойства" (Properties).
4. Вкладка Дополнительно (Advanced).
5. Справа поле "Свойства" (Value).
6. Вписываете без двоеточий и пробелов новый MAC адрес.
7. Перезагружаетесь.

**Сменить MAC в Ubuntu**:

```
sudo gedit /etc/network/interfaces

//Увидите эти строчки, но могут быть варианты.
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp

//На эти
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
       hwaddress ether 01:02:03:04:05:06

sudo /etc/init.d/networking restart
```

В других Linux это сделать не сложнее.

Есть и программы, чтобы не лезть никуда, но я не думаю, что Вам сложно набрать в google "*программа для смены MAC адреса*". Но хочу предостеречь, ибо, сменив MAC, Вы не обезопасили себя, разве что можно обойти блокировку по MAC, например, в Wi-fi сетях.

**Принцип работы роутера совсем по-простому:**

1. DCHP сервер на роутере выдает Вашему устройству IP адрес, Вы можете поменять его только в настройках роутера, Ваш IP для роутера менять не имеет смысла, обычно это 127.0.0.1.
2. Для связи с интернетом роутер через "модем" или "кабель" также запрашивает IP адрес у провайдера интернета. Поэтому его тоже изменить нельзя, разве что Вы провайдер.
3. У Ваших устройств есть доступ к интернету с тем IP, который Вам выдали.

Исходя из всего вышеизложенного, если *Вы не провайдер* или *не ФСБ*, то выяснить личность размещавшего объявление невозможно.

> "Хотите, чтобы Вас не обнаружили в
> сети? - Не пользуйтесь сетью."

Answer (score 0):

У провайдера о Вас есть вся информация, которая обязательно поможет идентифицировать Вас. Сменив ip адрес и mac, спрятаться не получиться, так как еще есть номер порта маршрутизатора, от которого идет кабель в квартиру. Также сменив mac и ip, вы можете быть заблокированы на маршрутизаторах провайдера, файрволом или другими средствами.